# Chaining limit() in mongo to avoid return of all result

Tags: mongodb

Would the following query:

```
db.collection.find() \
.limit(<max no. of item to return>) \
.skip(<(pageIndex-1)*no. of item to display>) \
.limit(<no. of item to display>)
```

Still performs the first limiter "max no. of item to return" or the second limiter "no. of item to display", will be honored.

E.g. if I have 10,000 records

I would like to cap the maximum pagination at 5,000th records, but display 100 per pager index and the would yield me a 50 pages of results, regardless if the 10,000 records grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` only supports a single `limit`, but you can use an aggregation pipeline to do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$limit: n},
    {$skip: (pageIndex-1)*m},
    {$limit: m}
])
```

However, note that you'll always be reading all `n` records from the collection, so it's probably better to perform this check in business logic instead.